# How to Force Phalcon to pick view from another module instead of defined?

Tags: model-view-controller, phalcon, dispatcher, phalcon-orm

Currently I am loading all users on URL/Route `/admin/config/users` which is picking this view ( `private/apps/Admin/Views/user/users.volt` ) from Admin module.

Now I have set a flag for custom layout. So if custom layout is enabled I want the phalcon to pick view from AdminExtension module i.e ( `private/apps/Admin/Extension/Views/user/users.volt` )

How can I achive this? I want both views. Because `private/apps/Admin/Views/user/users.volt` is default view for listing all users. However `private/apps/Admin/Extension/Views/user/users.volt` is customised view for client where a lot of design changes are done.

Here is how dispatcher code looks like:

```
/**
 * @param Dispatcher $dispatcher
 */
public function afterExecuteRoute(Dispatcher $dispatcher) {

    // Check if Json response is required
    if ($this->_isJsonResponse) {
         //if body
    } else {

        if(CxSettingCustomLayout::loadFromDb()->isCustomLayout()) {
            //pick custom view here" `private/apps/Admin/Extension/Views/user/users.volt`
        }

        // Build current module configuration settings section name
        $moduleConfigName = 'app_' . $this->dispatcher->getModuleName();
        // Include assets configuration file where assets collections are defined
        if(file_exists($this->config[ $moduleConfigName ]['assetsFile']))
            include $this->config[ $moduleConfigName ]['assetsFile'];

        // Set a view variable with the current language code
        $this->view->setVar('current_language_code', $this->CxTranslation->getLanguage()->getCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: You want this? `$this->view->render`  or check methods You want to use: https://docs.phalcon.io/3.4/en/api/phalcon_mvc_view

Comment: also check `setViewsDir`, `setLayoutsDir` read manual: https://docs.phalcon.io/3.4/en/api/phalcon_mvc_view#methods

Answer (score 1):

As @num8er said already, try to use `setViewsDir`. I'm using Phalcons `Simple` view class in the following way

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\View\Simple;

$view = new Simple();
$view->setViewsDir(BASE_PATH . '/app/views/');
echo $view->render('admin/users');
```